# Change number input to characters

Tags: javascript

I built this simple script to input a certain number,

Now I want to use this but with characters, how would I change the `Num ==` input and what would I change it to?

Many Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_number()
{
    var num = document.getElementById('input_number').value;
    if (num == smaller){
        document.getElementById('result_image_correct').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('result_image_incorrect').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('result_image_correct2').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('result_image_incorrect').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('result_image_correct').style.display = 'none';
        }

}
</script>
```

Comment: What is `smaller` in your example? Where is it defined?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? What is the HTML markup this applies to? Where does `smaller` come from and how does that relate to character data?

Comment: a number would normally go here but i want it to check for the characters "smaller" instead of a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just change `smaller` to `"smaller"` or `'smaller'`.